# Sending a DKIM signed email - Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib, dkim

How would I DKIM sign an email I've constructed using `email.mime.text.MIMEText` and am sending using `smtplib`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047831/generating-dkim-signatures-via-python-for-custom-mta/37300501#37300501 This should help

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's the mail server's job to add this signature.

Comment: The SMTP server I'm using doesn't do DKIM signing.

Comment: Then how come that be: Outlook adds extra DKIM headers and php soft doesn't http://serverfault.com/questions/418461/phpmailer-email-goes-to-spam-outlook-email-doesnt

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use:

```
import skim
sign = dkim.sign(msg.as_string(),'key', 'domain.com', private_key)
```

(but is not working, I dont know why)