# Generating DKIM signatures VIA Python for Custom MTA

Tags: python, email, base64, sha256, dkim

Ok, so I am not completely lost with DKIM. I know the general rules of encoding and setting DNS records with your public key, etc. What I am having issues with is incorporating the "on the fly" signing of outbound emails and injecting into my header because my MTA it is custom, written in python from the ground up, not out of the box. Wondering if anyone had a small python example of sending even 1 email with DKIM, and going through all the motions. Like generating the 256 bit crypto body using your private key that matches the sister (public) key in your dns settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help.

https://launchpad.net/dkimpy

I looked at the tests and the command line tools included in the project to learn how to use it.

Here is a code fragment which will give you an idea of how to use it. Sorry I can't provide more.

```
    self.dkim_private = open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_DIR, 'private_key.pem')).read()
    ... snip ...
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = "{0} <{1}>".format(self.sendfrom_name, self.sendfrom)
    msg['To'] = self.sendto
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Message-ID'] = self.message_id
    msg['Subject'] = self.subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', self.body_text), 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(self.body, 'html'))

    sig = dkim.sign(msg.as_string(), 'myselector',
                    from_domain, self.dkim_private,
                    include_headers=['from', 'to', 'subject', 'message-id'])
    msg['DKIM-Signature'] = sig[len("DKIM-Signature: "):]
```

Then you use can use smtplib to send the email.

The private and public keys can be generated easily here:

https://www.port25.com/support/domainkeysdkim-wizard/

Comment: Not sure why, but I kept getting `bytes` related errors. converting all parameters to `dkim.sign()` like so: `dkim.sign(bytes(msg.as_string(), 'UTF-8'), b'myselector', ...)` worked. Not sure if this is a Python2 vs Python3 thing, but sure smells like it.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to thank Georg Zimmer for the answer below.  I ran into some difficulties running this on Python 3.6.2 as some of the "byte" / "string" items have changed since 2.x versions.  Below is code to make a MIMEMultipart (text/HTML) and signed with DKIM.  I used dkimpy-0.6.2.

My very first StackOverflow post.  Hope it helps you...

```
import smtplib, dkim, time, os

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['From'] = 'test@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'person@anotherexample.com'
msg['Subject'] = ' Test Subject'
msg['Message-ID'] = "<" + str(time.time()) + "-1234567890@example.com" + ">"

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = """\
Test email displayed as text only
"""

html = """\
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <title>Test DKMI Email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        HTML Body of Test DKIM
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# DKIM Private Key for example.com RSA-2048bit
privateKey = open(os.path.join('C:\\dev\\python\\', '2048.example.com.priv')).read()

# Specify headers in "byte" form
headers=[b'from', b'to', b'subject', b'message-id']

# Generate message signature
sig = dkim.sign(msg.as_bytes(), b'introduction', b'example.com', privateKey.encode(), include_headers=headers)
sig = sig.decode()

# Add the DKIM-Signature
msg['DKIM-Signature'] = sig[len("DKIM-Signature: "):]

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 2):

To build on the previous two answers, I have a few additional tips.

1. Be sure you run

```
pip install dkimpy
```

2. Generate the private key. On Unix:

```
openssl genrsa -out dkimprivatekey.pem 1024
```

3. Generate the public. On Unix:

```
openssl rsa -in dkimprivatekey.pem -out public.pem -pubout
```

4. Add the public key to your DNS with the selector "introduction" (which is what the example above uses.
5. Provide the path and filename to your private key in the code above (the example above uses `C:\dev\python\` and `2048.example.com.priv`)

Comment: This answer must be removed. Doesn't answer the qquestion